# C# Regex boundary with special characters

Tags: c#, regex

I want to have a Regex that finds "Attributable".
I tried `@"\bAttributable\b"` but the \b boundary doesn't work with special characters.

For example, it wouldn't differentiate Attributable and Non-Attributable. Is there any way to Regex for **Attributable** and not it's negative?

Comment: Try `@"(?<!\S)Attributable(?!\S)"` if you only want to look for words that are between whitespaces/start/end of string. Actually, if it is what you want, you may do without a regex by using `s.Split().Contains("Attributable")`.

Comment: Are you sure a single `(?<!-)` is what you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a negative look-behind?

```
(?<!-)\bAttributable\b
```

Obviously this only checks for `-`s. If you want to check for other characters, put them in a character class in the negative look-behind:

```
(?<![-^])\bAttributable\b
```

Alternatively, if you just want to not match `Non-Attributable` but do match `SomethingElse-Attributable`, then put `Non-` in the look-behind:

```
(?<!Non-)\bAttributable\b
```

Comment: Works but isn't really what I'm trying to make. I want it to search for "Attributable" itself regardless of whatever special character or anything

Comment: @JarrenOng How do you define "By itself"? Computers are not like us, who can see whether that's `Attributable` "by itself" just by looking at it. You have to make a rule like "surrounded by whitespace means by itself". So what's your rule for determining this?

Comment: Hmm that makes sense. I wanted it to be "Attributable" with boundary of no character besides whitespace. But /. would not work with hyphens. 
[^-]\bAttributable\b works thanks

Comment: @JarrenOng Are you sure `[^-]\bAttributable\b` does what you want? If you just want spaces, why not just `" Attributable "` (without the quotes)? Also, if you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it!

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to fix the issue like you have but it all depends on the real requirements. It is sometimes necessary to precise what "word boundary" you need in each concrete case, since [**`\b` word boundary**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) is 1) context dependent, and 2) matches specific places in the string that you should be aware of:

> - Before the first character in the string, if the first character is a
>     word character.
> - After the last character in the string, if the last
>     character is a word character.
> - Between two characters in the string,
>     where one is a word character and the other is not a word character.

Now, here are several approaches that you may follow:

- When you only care about compound words usually joined with hyphens (similar [@Sweeper's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46538100/3832970)): [`(?<!-)\bAttributable\b(?!-)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!-%29%5cbAttributable%5cb%28%3f!-%29&i=l%27Attributable+Any-Attributable+Attributable-Any+O%e2%80%99Attributable+Attributable+%2cAttributable)
- Only match between whitespaces or start/end of string: [`(?<!\S)Attributable(?!\S)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5cS%29Attributable%28%3f!%5cS%29&i=l%27Attributable+Any-Attributable+O%e2%80%99Attributable+Attributable+%2cAttributable). **NOTE**: Actually, if it is what you want, you may do without a regex by using [`s.Split().Contains("Attributable")`](https://ideone.com/QZIWoG)
- Only match if not preceded with punctuation and there is no letter/digit/underscore right after: [`(?<!\p{P})Attributable\b`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5cp%7bP%7d%29Attributable%5cb&i=l%27Attributable+Any-Attributable+O%e2%80%99Attributable+Attributable+%2cAttributable)
- Only match if not preceded with punctation symbols *but* some specific ones (say, you want to match the word after a comma and a colon): [`(?<![^\P{P},;])Attributable\b`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c!%5b%5e%5cP%7bP%7d%2c%3b%5d%29Attributable%5cb&i=l%27Attributable+Any-Attributable+Attributable-Any+O%e2%80%99Attributable+Attributable+%2cAttributable+%3bAttributable).